# 'std::system_error', producer consumer C++ concurrency

Tags: c++, concurrency, condition-variable

The Producer/Consumer program below should transfer a character at a time to the buffer and then print it. The program initially runs, but then always fail on the third iteration of the consumer loop. -pthread is included at compile time.

The program should be able to iterate through the 'poem' variable, eventually resulting in the entire poem being printed out, character by character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

mutex mtx;
condition_variable cond_var;
int thread_ID = 1;

vector<char> txtImport(vector<char> output){
  ifstream file("poem.txt");
  char character;
  while (file.get(character)){
    output.push_back(character);
  }
  return output;
}

void producer(vector<char> poem, char* buffer, int poem_size) {
  cout << "\n\nPROD-  \n";
  int poem_position = 68;
  const int producer_ID = 1;
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
  while(true){
    cout << "\n1";
    if(poem_position == poem_size) {exit(1);}
    if(thread_ID!=producer_ID) {cond_var.wait(lock);}
    else{
      cout << "\nlock\n";

      *buffer = poem[poem_position];
      poem_position += 1;
      thread_ID = 2;

      cout << poem_position << " 2 \n";
      cout << poem[poem_position] << " 4 \n";
      cout << "CHAR: " << *buffer << " \n------\n\n";

      lock.unlock();
      cond_var.notify_all();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
  }
}

void consumer(char* buffer){
  cout << "\n\n       -CONS\n";
  const int consumer_ID = 2;
  unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
  while(true){
    cout << "\n       one ";
    if(thread_ID!=consumer_ID) {cond_var.wait(lock);}
    else{
      cout << "\n       lock\n";
      cout << "       ->" << *buffer << " <-\n\n";
      thread_ID = 1;
      lock.unlock();
      cond_var.notify_all();
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {

    vector<char> poem;
    poem = txtImport(poem);
    char buffer = 'z';
    int poem_size = poem.size();

    cout << "\n--MAIN--\n";

    thread thread_two(consumer, &buffer);
    thread thread_one(producer, poem, &buffer, poem_size);


    thread_one.join();
    thread_two.join();

    return 0;

}
```

The program output is:

```
--MAIN--


       -CONS

       one 

PROD-  

1
lock
69 2 
b 4 
CHAR: m 
------


       one 
       lock
       ->m <-


1
lock
70 2 
e 4 
CHAR: b 
------


       one 
       lock
       ->b <-

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
terminate called recursively
  what():  Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: can you clean up the code to a minimum reproducible example, you have a lot of code that isn't used or does nothing, and your variable passing is very unclear.. txtImport for starters isn't important and is poorly written, you care copying the vector repeatedly for no reason.. is this your first go at c++? either pass in by reference and return nothing or a bool for failure, or simply return a vector to get Return value optimization and pass nothing in ( but perhaps the FILENAME is what you should be passing in.. ) and if you are using a stream why use get? use an operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour.

When `cond_var.wait` is called, passed mutex must be locked by current thread. It doesn't happen in your code (except first iteration).

Your case:

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
while (true)
   cond_var.wait(lock);
   lock.unlock();
```

so in second iteration of *while* loop, when `wait` is called `lock` is unlocked. Wrong.

To fix, move `unique_lock` construction inside **both** (the same issue in consumer/producer functions) *while* loops.

---

> lock  -   an object of type std::unique_lock, which must be
>   locked by the current thread

from [condition_variable::wait reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait).

Comment: please could you clarify what you mean by:

'To fix, move unique_lock construction inside both'

Comment: @A.Simpson I mean this `while(true){ unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx); .. the rest code 1:1 ... }`. I made typo with for/while names. `lock` is constructed inside while() body.